# loop in bash script from prepared list global variables

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I would like to iterate over the list of text lines, ex.: `CONFIG_SERVER_USER="client"` , `CONFIG_SERVER_PASS="s3cr3t"`, `CONFIG_SERVER_PORT=8881`
to replace them in a repetitive activity inside the bash file, ex.:

```
if [[ -z ${CONFIG_SERVER_USER+x} ]]; then
  echo "Global Variables set up:"
  echo CONFIG_SERVER_USER="client" >> /etc/environment
  source /etc/environment
else
  echo "Required Global Variable already exists:"
fi
echo "CONFIG_SERVER_USER: $CONFIG_SERVER_USER"
#
```

and in above ex. should be replaced: `CONFIG_SERVER_USER="client"`, as well in result echo `"CONFIG_SERVER_USER: $CONFIG_SERVER_USER"`

Comment: You can iterate easiy with with bash's arrays

Comment: and what about quotes? aren't they necessary?

Comment: Yes, quotes are necessary, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: it is not usable, better is: `declare -a array=(["CONFIG_SERVER_USER"]="client" ["CONFIG_SERVER_PASS"]="s3cr3t" ["CONFIG_SERVER_PORT"]=8881 ["DISCOVERY_SERVER_PORT"]=8891)` but how to build condition? `if [[ -z ${"$key"+x} ]]; then` is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A dflts=(
    [CONFIG_SERVER_USER]='client'
    [CONFIG_SERVER_PASS]='s3cr3t'
    [CONFIG_SERVER_PORT]='888'
)

# just to test with one variable set
CONFIG_SERVER_PASS='12345'

for name in "${!dflts[@]}"; do
    if [[ -z "${!name+x}" ]]; then
        # echo "Global Variables set up:"
        # printf "%s='%s'\n" "$name" "${dflts[$name]}" >> /etc/environment
        # source /etc/environment
        printf "Not set: %s='%s'\n" "$name" "${dflts[$name]}"
    else
        # echo "Required Global Variable already exists:"
        printf "Set: %s='%s'\n" "$name" "${!name}"
    fi
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
Not set: CONFIG_SERVER_PORT='888'
Not set: CONFIG_SERVER_USER='client'
Set: CONFIG_SERVER_PASS='12345'
```

Uncomment the parts writing to your env file when you're done testing.

Comment: big thnx works fine :)

Comment: @EdMorton Have a look at [my another version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77118022/1765658) which is a little shorter (why did you `source`  you environment ;-)

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub the only difference I see is you're using `-v` (to only test for set) where I duplicated the OPs `-z` comparison (to test for set or null) and you haven't included the OPs code for echo-ing and populating their environment file. As for "why did you source you environment" - that's me just copying the OPs code (commented out) after answering their question about how to loop on the variables so it's clear to them how their code fits into the solution.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, **and** I assign *default* variables by using  `${!name:=${dflt[$name]}}`. (And accessory, I use `declare -p ${!CONFIG_*}` to show usage of another bashism that use excamation mark for another purpose than indirection. ;) - The OP's request of echoing this in another file is commented out, but present.

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub That's fine and it's a reasonable additional thing to do but the OP didn't ask about any of that and it doesn't make your code answering the question any shorter than mine. Comments aren't typically considered as code when comparing number of lines of code between 2 programs.

Comment: ...and quicker: As I write to `/etc` file **outside** of loop, I will access fs only 1 time! Not for each unassigned value in the loop.

Comment: If a variable is **assigned** to *nothing*: `CONFIG_SERVER_PASS=""`, your script will reassign them as they was **not** initialised.

Comment: Again, you're comparing your additional code to read/write the environment file to the OPs additional code to do that, not my code to answer the question the OP asked about how to iterate through variables to your code to answer the question OP asked which is identical to mine except you're choosing to use `-v` instead of `-x` as the OP is using and you're choosing not to show the OP where their additional original code would fit into the new structure but instead write new code for them that you think is better for that purpose - fine.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you using `bash` arrays:

```
user="client" pass="s3cr3t" port=8881

if ((${#config_server[@]} != 3 )); then
    echo "Global Variables Arrays set up:"
    echo 'declare -A config_server' >> /etc/environment
    for x in user pass port; do
        echo "config_server[$x]=${!x}" >> /etc/environment
    done
    source /etc/environment
else
    echo "Required Global Array Variable already exists:"
fi

echo 'config_server array:'
for x in "${!config_server[@]}"; do
    echo "$x: ${config_server[$x]}"
done
```

---

[Don't use UPPER case variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

---

`((...))` and `$((...))` are arithmetic commands, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

---

Arrays:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashSheet#Arrays
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays

Comment: but what is `config_server`, where it is established?

Comment: `config_server` is the name of the array. We iterate over each keys/values to generate the array in environnement file, then source it. Take a look to the file.